# Strange dots next to images (Remove underline to anchor tag )

Tags: html, css

I have made a site for a school project and everything was fine until I saw those dots/lines next to the buttons. Here is an image.
[image]

My code for the images is:

CSS

```
 .button1 {
 overflow:hidden;
 left:50%;
 padding-right: 35px;
 padding-top: 20px;
 }
 .button2 {
 overflow:hidden;
 left:50%;
 padding-right: 35px;
 }
 .button3 {
 overflow:hidden;
 left:50%;
 padding-right: 35px;
 }

 .button4 {
 overflow:hidden;
 left:50%;
 padding-right: 35px;
 }
```

HTML

```
<div>
   <a href="menu.pdf" > <img src="images/button1.png" class="button1">
   <a href="Lmenu.html"> <img src="images/button2.png" class="button2">
   <a href="brunch.html"> <img src="images/button3.png" class="button3"> </a>
   <a href="FD.html"> <img src="images/button4.png" class="button4"> </a>
</div>
```

Comment: can you provide a fiddle?.

Comment: Can you make it a jsfiddle? If you use the F12 tools and inspect the _dots_ can you see which styling is on it?

Comment: Thanks but I found a solution!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The **space** between `<a href=...>` and `<img src=...>` is treated as printable text by the browser, and because it is inside the hyperlink tag, it is underlined.

Just remove the spaces, so use `<a href=...><img src=...></a>`.

Besides that: you forgot a couple of `</a>` closing tags. Best to add them in.

Comment: I taught of it, but it seems not to be the problem :/

Comment: I'm still quite convinced that it is the problem.

Comment: Oww. . .  the missing '</a>' were the problem :D, thanks !

Comment: Indeed, the missing `</a>` were causing the linefeed after it to also be treated as whitespace-inside-the-hyperlink, and thus even more 'text' to be underlined.

Answer (score 2):

Two things to point out.

1. Use the css `text-decoration:none;` For the anchor tag. without this it causes the text to have a underline.
2. There are missing `</a>` tag for few of your anchor tags.

The actual reason is **by default the anchor link will have a underline**, The default anchor link CSS rule is **`text-decoration:underline`** This is how the browser displays the anchor link. So all the text inside anchor will have a underline to it. In your case you have a space, And its the underline for the space.
So add this CSS rule to the anchor tag.

```
 a{
   text-decoration:none;
  }
```